# NPM, Package installation event emitter error

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

[Empty Folder Causing Memory Leak Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMPxD.png)

npm install -g npm@next
(node:2640) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Following threads online I have tried adding more event listeners - which does nothing.
I can run the app successfully, but when trying to add (any) new package example excelJS I keep receiving the error above.

I have received this error before and successfully got rid of it by doing a fresh install of nodeJS and NPM - have tried again and cannot resolve it.

I've tried creating a fresh directory/repository with no items and then do npm init followed by npm insall exceljs
This then provides the error message.

** FIXED for 2 x new packages **

I used: npm cache clean --force

** Now have original error **

I've created an empty folder and then done npm init, followed by npm install mssql
I then get the memory leak error.

Is it possible my NPM is corrupt?

Comment: After further testing and problems with other package/module installers like Pip and composer, I believe this problem is related to the VPN/Proxy server my company uses.
as soon as I disconnected the VPN it worked, then reconnecting caused the error.